# prevent google from indexing my page

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using asp.net mvc and I want to exclude google to index `Download` action. This action renders view under `Views/Download` so should I put inside robots.txt

```
User-agent: googlebot Disallow: /download
```

or

```
User-agent: googlebot Disallow: /views/download
```

Comment: If you are using the standard routes, use /{controller}/{action}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the path that visitors would use to get to the controller action you want to block off.  IIS shouldn't serve the view templates at all anyway - it's the action that gives the traction ;)